# How to structure a dynamic query with linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to build a dataset that I can throw out to a spreadsheet and I must admit that I have reached saturation point!!
These are my tables:

```
**Matrix**
Employee id
Template id
Expiry date

**Employee** 
Id
Employee Name

**Template**
Template Id
Template Name
```

What I am trying to achieve is a list of all employees (where employees will make up the rows of the dataset) and a list of all templates (templates are the column heads) I then need to populate the grid for each employee for each template with their expiry date. Some employees won’t have an expiry date for each template as they haven’t yet achieved certification.

I was thinking of creating a list of employees and then adding that employees collection of Matrix objects, but that wouldn't necessarily work as not everyone will have every template type as an entry in the matrix.

I have worked with linq for some years, but I am a bit stumped here because of how dynamic this data set is to build. New templates are added regularly so need including without maintenance to the query. Is it even possible by using linq, or do I need to look at building a view in SQL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below is a simple example of what I am trying to do!

```
        Temp1       temp2       temp3       temp4
Emp1    01/01/2014  02/6/2015               04/06/2012
Emp2                02/6/2015           
Emp3    01/05/2010
```

This is my data structure:

[image]

**Edit**

Well, I did manage to get something to work that I can output on to a view in the format I described, but I don't know if it is particularly efficient - If there is a better way I would love to know how!

```
   public class EmpMatrix
    {
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Classemptemp 
    {
        public emp Employee { get; set; }
        public List<EmpMatrix> tempateList { get; set; } 
    }

    public DateTime? GetExpiry(int template, int empl)
    {
        return (from a in _entities.matrices
            where a.empid == empl && a.tempId == template
            select a.expiryDate).FirstOrDefault();
    }


    public List<Classemptemp> testing()
    {
        List<emp> employees = _entities.emps.ToList();
        List<template> TemplateList = _entities.templates.ToList();
        List<Classemptemp> empList = (from employee in employees
            let matrix = TemplateList.Select(template => new EmpMatrix
            {
                TemplateId = template.templateId, TemplateName = template.Name, ExpiryDate = GetExpiry(template.templateId, employee.Id)
            }).ToList()
            select new Classemptemp
            {
                Employee = employee, tempateList = matrix
            }).ToList();
        return empList;
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, yes it seems possible. You have been a bit vague however about what code you already have. Do you have a DbContext? Are you binding to a view? There are two stages to answer this, one: What query do I need and Two: how do I represent the data as a table like above.

Comment: I am using MVC, I was going to bind the query results to a data grid and then return from the controller action as a file result to stream the data straight back to the client as a csv.  I have an EDMX with each of those tables included and access the entites by use of _entites . So I can get a list of employees by saying _entities.employee.ToList();

Comment: I understand. Do you have navigational properties? What do your POCO classes look like?

Comment: Yes, the Matrix table templateId is an FK of template table templateId and the martix table employeeId is an FK of the employee table Id. all ID fields are int, expiry date is DateTime and employee name, template name are both string

Comment: Have you thought about using navigation properties? `public Employee Employee { get; set; }`

Comment: Ive just added an image to my original post, I have got navigation properties already on my 3 tables

Comment: Just before I type a nice long answer, are you using MVC View models? e.g. @model Matrix

Comment: Actually the more I think about it the more I think your question is just too vague. What is wrong with simply returning `_entities.Matrices.ToList()`?

Comment: there maybe the occasion where a template has no entries in the matrix table - I still need to be able to view that template as a column head even though there are no matrix entries

Comment: Start by creating your naviation properties.  Wait, you already have navigation properties in your model view, but not in your classes? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking you could be using the System.Data.DataTable class and do something like this:

```
public class MatrixCell
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public DataTable ProcessRow(DataTable table)
    {
        bool found = false;

        foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if ((string)row["Employeename"] == EmployeeName)
            {
                found = true;
                row[ColumnName] = Date;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!found)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Employeename"] = EmployeeName;
            row[ColumnName] = Date;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```

Every MatrixTable object represents one cell in your table.
Application to demonstrate:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new TestDB())
        {
            //Initialize DataTable
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            var columnNames = db.Templates.Select(t => t.TemplateName).ToArray();

            table.Columns.Add("Employeename", typeof(string));

            foreach (var name in columnNames)
            {
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn(name, typeof(DateTime));
                column.AllowDBNull = true;
                table.Columns.Add(column);
            }

            //Get Matrix objects
            var result = db.Matrices.Select(m => new MatrixCell
            {
                ColumnName = m.Template.TemplateName,
                Date = (DateTime)m.Date,
                EmployeeName = m.Employee.EmployeeName
            }).ToArray();

            //Populate datatable
            foreach (var matrix in result)
                table = matrix.ProcessRow(table);

            Console.Read();
        }

    }
}
```

This will create a DataTable with the templatenames as the columnames. Every row represents an employee and the Datetimes for the corresponding templates are filled in. Then you can pass this DataTable to your view to display it.

I hope this could work!

Edit: I tested it for a few db values and it seems to be working. It is possible to make `Employeename` a primary key instead of a column.

Answer (score 0):

Class (or change IEnumerable to IQueryable if you datacontext is still around):

```
public MyViewModel {
  IEnumerable<emp> emps;
  IEnumerable<template> templates;
}
```

Controller:

```
var emps=db.emps
  .Include(e=>e.matrices)
  .Include(e=>e.matrices.template);
var templates=db.templates;
var model=new MyViewModel { emps=emps,templates=templates };
return model;
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel
<thead><tr>
@foreach(var template in model.templates)
{
  <th>@template.Name</th>
}
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
@foreach(var emp in model.emps)
{
  <tr>
  @foreach(var template in model.templates)
  {
    <td>
       @(emp.matrices.Any(m=>m.templateId==template.templateId)?
         emp.matrices.First(m=>m.templateId==template.templateId).toString("G"):
         "")
    </td>
  }
  </tr>
}
</tbody>
```